# Why we Need CallBack Function in Js Why we Don't Simply Call Function in Main Function?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback

Why Doesn't we call other function over callbacks function

```
function serverRequest(query, callback){
  setTimeout(function(){
    var response = query + "full!";
    callback(response);
  },5000);
}

function getResults(results){
  console.log("Response from the server: " + results);
}

serverRequest("The glass is half ", getResults);
```

SomeThing like this

```
function serverRequest(query){
  setTimeout(function(){
    var response = query + "full!";
    getResults(response);
  },5000);
}     
serverRequest("The glass is half");
```

Comment: In that particular example, you could use a global `getResults` function instead of passing it as an argument. We don't know why you don't.

Answer (score 2):

Callbacks's main purpose is to achieve asynchronous programming.

Callbacks are more useful when you want to expose an asynchronous API or you want to write asynchronous code that achieves separation of concerns and reusability.

for example, imagine like you are writing a small tool that gives people the ability to animate DOM elements.

you would give a function like the following:

```js
import MyCoolTweeningEngine from "lib/MyCoolTweeningEngine"

function animate(elem, props, callback) {
   MyCoolTweeningEngine(elem, props)
     .then((res) => res.json())
     .then(() => callback())
}
```

and people are gonna use your tool like this:

```js
animate(
  ".my-animated-element",
  { x: 100, scale: 1 },
  function () => console.log("animation finished"))
```

Callbacks were very common before Promises came along, now with Promises we can write relatively cleaner code:

```js
const res = await animate(".my-elem", { scale: 1 });
console.log("animation finished")
```

in your case, you can do this for cleaner and reusable code:

```js
import serverRequest from "../my-awesome-utils/serverRequest"


serverRequest("The glass is half ", function getResults(results){
  console.log("Response from the server: " + results);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you can call it direct because your functions `getResults` and `serverRequest` in the same scope and they have direct access to each other.

but there are situations when you need to use callback for example:

```
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

const MyCallback = (item) => {
  return item === 2;
};

arr.filter(MyCallback);
```

function `filter` in different scope and it doesn't know anything about your `MyCallback` function but it expects callback as props and apply it to each item of your array to check which item will return true

Answer (score 0):

But my Question Was What the use of callback if we can simply call that function without using a Callback.
So I actually get an answer after reading lots of articles of callbacks, asynchronous, synchronous, etc..

Use cases of Callback -

```
function add(a,b){
    return a+b;
}

function multiply(a,b){
    return a*b;
}

function remainder(a,b){
    return a%b;
}

function doSomething(a,b,callback){
    return callback(a,b);
}

doSomething(3,2,add)
// 5
doSomething(3,2,multiply)
// 6
doSomething(3,2,remainder)
// 1
```